# Eclipse -> Android Studio migration: how to include v4 support library (also including the ant build script)

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, android-studio

I have a setup of android project on eclipse and I want to migrate to Android Studio. So, I have android-support-v4.jar that I use for my main project and my Facebook lib-project.

I guess I have to exclude lib-projects as a folder in my main module (lets call the main module Jack). Jack has dependancy on the facebook lib-project.

How should I define the android-support-v4.jar as a separate library and use it in both projects? Or should I just use directly the jar files and leave them in both Jack's libs folder and Facebook libs folder?

If the first option should be done, will `ant clean release` still work (with the build.xml android generated file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android Studio, builds are done with Gradle now. Gradle is different. With gradle, you tell your project which jar's you need, and it will connect to a server and download them if it doesn't already have them when you compile your apk.

A few things to note:
When you install Android Studio, it has it's own Android sdk directory. You have to download everything from the sdk downloader (from inside the Android Studio App) again. Don't bother trying to switch the sdk download path to your current one. You will only encounter bugs (Or at least I did).

So your question is worded very confusingly. It sounds like you have a main module, and then you have a library module, and the library module uses the support library.

You'll need to set it up so the main module has a dependency on your library module. From there, you'll need to go into your library module's gradle file and tell it that you want to include the android support library

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
}
```

The support library is a little weird in gradle. Gradle normally would download the dependencies you need. However, android studio requires that you have the support library installed through their sdk downloader (top-right group of icons in android studio. The download icon).

After you get all your dependencies entered into your gradle file, you'll then need to go to Tools -> Android -> Sync gradle files with project. From there compile errors should go away, and you should be able to run the project.

Best of luck. By the way, Here is the documentation on Gradle on the android website. I find myself having to go to it A LOT, especially when I made the switch from Eclipse to Android Studio. This + Various tutorials I found as needed via google. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

EDIT: This link might also be helpful. Google has some steps for switching from eclipse to Android Studio: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html That with some of the stuff above may prove helpful.

Comment: Just ot clarify: both the main module, and the library are using the support library. Thanks for the answer, I'll dig it deeper tomorrow! Appreciate it!

Comment: @Danail Just to make sure you are aware. Since the library module is on your main modules build path you only have to declare the support library as a dependency in the library module.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tried this myself, I suggest you use the recommended migration steps provided by Google in [this article](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html).

Before you do that, though, make sure that you either:

Check that both support libraries on the main project and dependencies have the same version (Eclipse will complain about it during build time, and will likely cause problems during conversion to Gradle script.); OR,

Uncheck the "Android Private Libraries" entry on the Order and Export tab of the dependency project's build settings.

If the migration process described doesn't work smoothly for you, you can always call the Ant build script from within the Gradle script, as described [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ant.html).

Answer (score 0):

The Android Studio uses only Gradle, but you can export Android ant project from eclipse.
To do that go to `File -> import project` usually next, next, next... works.
If not go to project setting `Shift + Ctrl + Alt + S` and under `modules -> PROJECT_NAME -> Dependencies` you can add your support library.
To add a Facebook library you must add it as another module to your project.
If you still want to use Ant there is another option: Use `Intellij IDEA` which support Ant.